# Lambda function does not invoke cloudtrail logs

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am working on a python script that will store JSON attributes like ("region","ebs_volume_size","instance_type")inside a dynamodb table using a lambda function. This my lambda function which is taking an input from my python function for the policy:

```
import boto3
import time
import json
import meta_templates
from jinja2 import Template
from template_utils import create_aws_iam_policy_template 

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
lambd = boto3.client('lambda')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  template_json = create_aws_iam_policy_template(**event)

  table = dynamodb.Table('GoodTable')
  response = table.put_item(
      Item= {
          'Content': 'Volume Size', 
          'Details': template_json.get('ebs_volume_size'),
      }
  )
  response = table.put_item(
      Item= {
          'Content': 'Instance Type', 
          'Details': template_json.get('instance_type'),
      }
  )
  response = table.put_item(
      Item= {
          'Content': 'Region', 
          'Details': template_json.get('region'),
      }
  )
```

I have given my IAM role DynamoDB full access and have created the DynamoDB table called "GoodTable", after I run this function I am not able to add anything to the DyanmoDB table and the function runs without any error too. I am not sure what might be going wrong.

Comment: What is your lambda executure role exactly?

Comment: Also did you check CloudWatch Logs? If there are erros, they are usually there.

Comment: Take a minute and debug what's going on in `response` objects. It might give you a hint